# how to solve a matrix equation in maple

Tags: maple

I have a program that does some work to get a matrix `w`, which is `3(n+1)` by `3(n+1)`. I have a vector `fbar` that is `3(n+1)` by `1`. I want to get the matrix that, when `w` is multiplied by it, gives `fbar`.

In mathematical notation, `w * A = fbar`. I have `w` and `fbar`, and I want `A`.

I tried to solve it with this command:

```
fsolve({seq(multiply(w, A)[i, 1] = fbar[i, 1], i = 1 .. 3*(n+1))})
```

but I don't understand the response Maple gave:

```
fsolve({2.025881905 A1[2,1]+7.814009150 A1[3,1]+...  

-7.071067816 10^(-13) A1[3,1]-0.0004999999990 

A1[4,1]-0.0007071067294 A1[5,1]-0.0004999999990 A1[6,1]) 

A3[6,1]=0},{A1[1,1],A1[2,1],A1[3,1],A1[4,1],A1[5,1],A1[6,1],A\

2[1,1],A2[2,1],A2[3,1],A2[4,1],A2[5,1],A2[6,1],A3[1,1],A3[2,1]\

,A3[3,1],A3[4,1],A3[5,1],A3[6,1]})
```

What does this mean, and how can I get a more meaningful answer?

Comment: you'll need to format your code first

Comment: what do you mean?I wrote it. and its result. my program is much longer to write it here, if you mean that. but if its important, tell me please

Comment: I meant this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. But Andrew Piliser already formatted it for you.

Comment: yes. and thanks to him.and thank you too. but is there any guidance for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly with the `LinearSolve` functional from the `LinearAlgebra` package if `w` and `fbar` are defined as a matrix and vector respectively. The below code makes a reproducible example. Note that the solution of `LinearSolve` should be equal to `x`.

```
w := Matrix(<<1,2,3>|<4,5,6>|<7,8,10>>);
LinearAlgebra[ReducedRowEchelonForm](%); ## Full rank => 1 solution)
x := <1,2,3>;
fbar := w.x;


## Solve the equation w.x = fbar
LinearAlgebra[LinearSolve](w,fbar);
```

Comment: thank you. but when I use command you wrote above, I receive this error:


      Error, (in LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve) inconsistent system